# What is wrong with my Precision-Recall curve?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

[image]

Hi,
I found this:
https://github.com/rafaelpadilla/Object-Detection-Metrics
I prepared my data: ground-truth and prediction files with bounding boxes.
but I got a very strange plot. What do you thing?

Comment: Why do you think it’s strange? Looks OK to me

Comment: Because my plot start from 0 not from 1 (precision). End recall max value is only 0.32. It is my firsy precision-recall curve. I compere it to plots on Internet and I didn't find any similar to my plot.

Comment: Do you wanna elaborate how you've changed the threshold?

Answer (score 1):

Overall the performance of the model is very low, since precision and recall can be up to 1.

Since model performance is low, it will be sensitive to noise resulting in erratic behavior.